# How to change a table to partition table with DBMS_REDEFINITION but no primary key in current table

Tags: oracle, partition, database-partitioning

How to convert a non-partition table (no primary key) to partitioned table? Someone says I can use rowid, but I can not find any sample from Oracle doc.

My oracle is 12C release 1, it did not contain the new feature *Using the MODIFY clause of ALTER TABLE to convert online to a partitioned table*.

Please provide a sample if you can.

Comment: @APC ，I do not know how to convert a non-partition table(no primary key) to partitioned table ，Someone says can use rowid,but I can not find any sample from oracle doc, could you pls advise any solutions on convert non-partitioned table to partitioned table？

Answer (score 0):

> "Someone says can use rowed, but I can not find any sample from oracle doc"

I think the option you are looking for is the `DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE` parameter `options_flag`.

Like this

```
start_redef_table (
    uname => 'your_schema'
    , orig_table => 'your_current_table'
    , int_table => 'your_interim_table'
    , options_flag => dbms_redefinition.cons_use_rowid
);
```

[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042)

Comment: yes.seems like this，can help provide whole sample？Thx in advance.

Comment: As I want to know whether there exists some special treatments due to we use rowid. So could you pls help provide whole sample that convert non partition table to partitioned table